# How to run a Simple C Program in Eclipse IDE

Tags: c, eclipse, windows-7

I've downloaded Eclipse  C/C++ IDE . I need to run a simple c program in this(To print welcome).

While trying to run the program its popping up an error message  like `"Launch failed: Binary not found" .`

Need i install any compiler package. ?

Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you have to install a compiler, Eclipse is only an IDE. You can get MinGW [here](http://www.mingw.org/).

Answer (score 5):

http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/

Look at the above link,you will get more idea,on how to do development using C/C++ using eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the documentation which comes along with the IDE.

Just on the start up window in Eclipse click Tutorials and then click on c/c++ development link and then read **Before you Begin**  part.

[image: Eclipse Help Guide]

Answer (score 0):

The program you write must be converted into respective binary which is to be run on that particular architecture.This process is carried out by the compiler as a result compiler is required for eclipse IDE to compile and link the code .

Various compilers are available such as Microsoft Visual C++ MinGW GCC or Cygwin GCC in the form of chaintools in eclipse so as to compile the code.

Comment: He needs to build the program first, before running. He already has the compiler since he installed the correct Eclipse version.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is an IDE.It will help you write applications in c/++,but it will not compile your program as Eclipse does not comes with a compiler pre-configured.

You need to install a compiler to run your application.

Eclipse is capable to use many c/c++ compilers,some are:

1.Cygwin

2.MingW

3.Gross

4.Microsoft Visual C++

[image: List of c/c++ compilers which can be used in Eclipse]

I would advise to install mingW OR Cygwin.

If you need more help on running a c/c++ application in Eclipse
visit  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecc/?S_TACT=105AGX44&S_CMP=ART